# Analysing global stability of a 1-dimensional system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Consider

\begin{align}
\frac{dS}{dt} &= \mu N -\frac{\beta S I}{N} - \nu S\\[2ex]
\frac{dI}{dt} &= \frac{\beta S I}{N} -\nu I
\end{align}
Where $N=S+I$ is the total population.

By substituting $S=N-I$ into the above we have:

\begin{align}
\frac{dI}{dt} &= (\beta - \nu)I - \beta I^2
\end{align}

Solving the above with initial condition $I(0)= I_0$ analytically, we have the solution to the system:

\begin{align}
I(t) &= \frac{I_0 (\beta - \nu)}{\beta I_0 - e^{-\left(\beta - \nu\right)t} \left[ \beta I_0 - \left(\beta - \nu\right)\right]}.\\[2ex]
S(t) &= 1-I(t).
\end{align}

We can make inferences of the long term behaviour of this model by examining the possible values of $\left(\beta -\nu\right)$, that is, of course when $I(t)$ is feasible. We have two cases
\begin{align*}
\beta - \nu & < 0 \\[2ex]
\beta - \nu & > 0
\end{align*}

If $\beta - \nu < 0$, then $e^{-\left(\beta - \nu\right)t} \rightarrow \infty \text{ as } t \rightarrow \infty$ hence

\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to \infty} I(t) = 0.
\end{align}

If $\beta - \nu > 0$, then $e^{-\left(\beta - \nu\right)t} \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } t \rightarrow \infty$ hence we have the limit

\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to \infty} I(t) = \frac{I_0\left(\beta-\nu\right)}{\beta I_0} = 1-\frac{\nu}{\beta}.
\end{align}

The equilibrium points:

\begin{align*}
e_1 : \left( S_1^*, I_1^*\right)&= \left(1, 0\right), \\[2ex]
e_2 : \left( S_2^*, I_2^*\right)&= \left(\frac{\nu }{\beta}, \frac{\nu}{\beta}\left(\frac{\beta}{\nu}-1 \right)\right)
\end{align*}

where $\mathcal{R}_0 = \beta/\nu$.

Using the monotonicity theorem, we can prove global stability of the equilibrium of interest on the line without ends by showing that the rhs is non-positive in the intervals to both sides of the equilibrium. How can I do this explicitly?

Comment: What do you mean with explicitly? (Note: that you actually do not need to solve it explicitely, you can just apply the stable manifold theorem for local stability, the globalness follows from the fact that you are dealing with a 1D system)

Comment: @Novo What I meant by explicitly is that I want a concrete answer :)